# Tomcat 8.5.31 stuck while deploying the war

Tags: java, apache, tomcat8

We are migrating our application from tomcat 7 to tomcat 8. All wars are deploying successfully in tomcat 8. But only one war is not deploying. Tomcat 8 starts deploying the war and then stuck there. No logs are printing in Catalina.out and Error.log.

Please find below logs.

```
23-May-2018 04:14:55.314 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.31
23-May-2018 04:14:55.328 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Apr 27 2018 20:24:25 UTC
23-May-2018 04:14:55.328 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.31.0
23-May-2018 04:14:55.328 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
23-May-2018 04:14:55.328 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64
23-May-2018 04:14:55.328 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
23-May-2018 04:14:55.328 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre
23-May-2018 04:14:55.328 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_60-b27
23-May-2018 04:14:55.328 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
23-May-2018 04:14:55.329 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.31
23-May-2018 04:14:55.329 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.31
23-May-2018 04:14:55.329 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
23-May-2018 04:14:55.329 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
23-May-2018 04:14:55.329 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
23-May-2018 04:14:55.329 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
23-May-2018 04:14:55.329 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
23-May-2018 04:14:55.330 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
23-May-2018 04:14:55.330 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat
23-May-2018 04:14:55.330 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat
23-May-2018 04:14:55.330 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp
23-May-2018 04:14:55.330 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
23-May-2018 04:14:55.644 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
23-May-2018 04:14:55.675 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
23-May-2018 04:14:55.706 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
23-May-2018 04:14:55.708 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
23-May-2018 04:14:55.720 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1282 ms
23-May-2018 04:14:55.755 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.checkPoolConfiguration maxIdle is smaller than minIdle, setting maxIdle to: 5
23-May-2018 04:14:57.653 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
23-May-2018 04:14:57.654 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.31
23-May-2018 04:14:57.711 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] **org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.31/webapps/llas.war]**
```

This is last line in Catalina.out.

Comment: Did you try _reading_ the log? Did you see the message `Unable to create directory for deployment: [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.31/conf/Catalina/localhost]`?

Comment: Propably the problem is with permissions. Try to create folder  `/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.31/conf/Catalina/localhost` and execute `chmod 777 /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.31/conf/Catalina/localhost`

Comment: Hi @JimGarrison . I have resolved the issue you addressed.Still getting same problem.

Comment: Hi @DanilaZharenkov. I have edited the my question and latest logs are attached. chmod 777 is executed for requested dir. Still facing same issue.

Comment: The new log DOES NOT contain an error preventing startup.

Comment: as @JimGarrison said, there are no errors in your log. Looks like tomcat started succesfully. Or this is not the full log

Comment: @DanilaZharenkov This is the full log. Deploying web application archive [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.31/webapps/llas.war] . This is last line in Catalina.out.

Comment: do you have in your pom file dependencies like `org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin` or `org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina` ? Or some other tomcat dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a VM, try to set

```
Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandomns
```

in the file setenv.sh

Source:
https://serverfault.com/questions/658502/tomcat-8-hangs-on-startup-while-deploying-webapp-possibly-related-to-entropy-ge

Answer (score 0):

Presenting this as a problem might not be as evident as described in the comments and linked resources. While the symptoms of my issue closely resemble those already mentioned here, i assume the reason may differ.

> It's important to note that the logs **NEVER** contained any errors
> preventing startup; Tomcat simply froze with 100% CPU usage.

We have a web app that is operational on Tomcat 9 with JDK 1.8. We've decided to enable the [Java Security Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html), utilizing the [pro-grade library](https://github.com/pro-grade/pro-grade) in [grant all mode](https://github.com/pro-grade/pro-grade#prograde-as-the-underlying-policy). I won't delve deeply into the specific rules used and the entire Tomcat configuration, as the Tomcat installation—including the Java Security Manager—was cloned from an already functioning application on another server. Both servers are virtual machines running Oracle Linux Server 6.

The only alteration made was in the bin/setenv.sh script, where we configured variables to enable the Java Security Manager.

## Working application configuration

JDK: /opt/jdk1.8.0_201/
Tomcat: Apache Tomcat/7.0.27

*Note: This example might not be ideal, as it's a development machine running  Tomcat 7, which could potentially be a contributing factor to the occurrence of this bug...*

```
$ cat bin/setenv.sh 
#!/bin/sh
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$CATALINA_HOME/lib/pro-grade-1.1.1-verbose.jar
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.manager=net.sourceforge.prograde.sm.ProGradeJSM -Djava.security.properties=file:$CATALINA_HOME/conf/SecurityManager/custom_java.security"
# Important! this one allows grant policy
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dprograde.use.own.policy=true"
```

Resulting startup command in the process list:

```
tomcat   35603  0.4 52.1 13509904 1967628 ?    Sl   Aug22  15:43 
/usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager 
-Djava.security.manager=net.sourceforge.prograde.sm.ProGradeJSM 
-Djava.security.properties=file:/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/conf/SecurityManager/custom_java.security 
-Dprograde.use.own.policy=true 
-Xms128m -Xmx3G -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-Dhttps.protocols=SSLv3,TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7777 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.1.2 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/endorsed 
-classpath :/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/lib/pro-grade-1.1.1-verbose.jar:/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/bin/tomcat-juli.jar 
-Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.27 -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.27 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/temp 
org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

**NB** This application is starting successfully called from service or manually using bin/catalina.sh

```
start() {
    daemon --user tomcat  "/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/bin/startup.sh"
}
```

## Failing application configuration

JDK: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_201/ (eventually it was updated to 381)
Tomcat: Apache Tomcat/9.0.22

- You might notice that I'm invoking it with urandom to eliminate the possibility of an entropy bug: *

```
bin/setenv.sh: cloned configuration from working app above
/etc/init.d/tomcat: same as above
```

Resulting startup command in the process list (called from service):

```
tomcat   10529  100 19.4 3987040 347372 ?      Sl   11:47  14:05 
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_381/bin/java 
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/storage/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager 
-Djava.security.manager=net.sourceforge.prograde.sm.ProGradeJSM 
-Djava.security.properties=file:/opt/storage/tomcat/conf/SecurityManager/custom_java.security 
-Dprograde.use.own.policy=true
-Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom  
-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources 
-Djdk.tls.maxHandshakeMessageSize=38096 
-Dignore.endorsed.dirs= 
-classpath :/opt/storage/tomcat/lib/pro-grade-1.1.1-verbose.jar:/opt/storage/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/storage/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar 
-Dcatalina.base=/opt/storage/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/opt/storage/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/storage/tomcat/temp 
org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

You can notice that process had 100% cpu usage. The log was similar to the one provided in the question—Tomcat froze during the deployment of the WAR file. To illustrate this point, I left it in such a state for a day, but no changes occurred.

Subsequently, I attempted to invoke it directly as the root user, resulting in the same freeze.

The next step was to try calling it directly as the tomcat user (a non-login user). Surprisingly, it succeeded.

```
tomcat   11135 61.5 36.1 4171984 644204 ?      Sl   12:07   0:44 
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_381/jre/bin/java 
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/storage/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager 
-Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom 
-Djava.security.manager=net.sourceforge.prograde.sm.ProGradeJSM 
-Djava.security.properties=file:/opt/storage/tomcat/conf/SecurityManager/customt_java.security 
-Dprograde.use.own.policy=true 
-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Djdk.tls.maxHandshakeMessageSize=38096 -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= 
-classpath :/opt/storage/tomcat/lib/pro-grade-1.1.1-verbose.jar:/opt/storage/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/storage/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar 
-Dcatalina.base=/opt/storage/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/opt/storage/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/storage/tomcat/temp 
org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

```
24-Aug-2023 19:20:48.368 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/storage/tomcat/webapps/preprod] has finished in [35,712] ms
24-Aug-2023 19:20:48.380 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [39,923] milliseconds
```

So, what comes next—file permission errors?!
I altered the service script to initiate Tomcat in the same way I had done by invoking it as the tomcat user, but it froze again...

It was now time to eliminate differences in the startup script configuration.
...

In short, on the new server, the Tomcat startup was fixed by removing the prepended colon in the classpath. The amusing thing is that it functions properly on the development server (though using Tomcat 7), even though the official classpath entry separator is a [semicolon](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

```
tomcat   16506  0.6 34.0 9488308 1381516 ?     Sl   Aug24   3:03 /usr/bin/java 
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/storage/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager 
-Djava.security.manager=net.sourceforge.prograde.sm.ProGradeJSM 
-Djava.security.properties=file:/opt/storage/tomcat/conf/SecurityManager/custom_java.security 
-Dprograde.use.own.policy=true 
-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Xms512M -Xmx2048M -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:8000,server=y,suspend=n -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= 
-classpath /opt/storage/tomcat/lib/pro-grade-1.1.1-verbose.jar:/opt/storage/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/storage/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/storage/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/opt/storage/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/storage/tomcat/temp 
org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

P.S. Please comment if you have any clues regarding the actual cause of this bug.